# Swift - Class Func Instance member 'x' cannot be used on type 'y'

Tags: ios, swift

Alert gives an error "**Instance member 'alert' cannot be used on type 'SendPhoto'**". I looked some answers but CustomAlertView Non-Void function. So i didnt figure it out.

```
class SendPhoto {
    var alert:CustomAlertView?
    class func sendPhotoToAssistant(){
        self.alert = CustomAlertView(title: "Title")
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your function name, it’s the same of your class and according to swift name convention should be camel case, for example: sendPhotoAction

Comment: I pay attention thank you for response but i didnt find any solution yet :(

Comment: You can't use a class function to assign values to properties belonging to instances of the class. And the name of the function 'send...' implies some kind of action but I don't see any.

Comment: To help you with the correct solution I think you need to tell us what the purpose of 'sendPhotoToAssistant()' is.

Comment: sendPhotoToAssistant() upload a photo to service with Alamofire

Comment: You're using `self` in a `class` function.

Comment: @AliIhsanURAL and that upload is handled by CustomAlertView?

Comment: No. Alertview just show a popup for process result like UIAlertView. Upload is handeled by Alamofire

Comment: @AliIhsanURAL, this makes no sense to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because `var alert` is only accessible within an instance function and you're trying to set it in a class function.
If you would like to set `var alert` you need to change your code to the following (also changed the function name to following Swift convention):

```
class SendPhoto {
    var alert: CustomAlertView?

    func sendPhoto() { // notice the lack of `class` in the declaration
        self.alert = CustomAlertView(title: "Title")

    }
}
```

Comment: But if I call this function from other VC , I have to write SendPhoto(). sendPhoto . Isn't it ?. But I dont want to write () after SendPhoto.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your alert as class func you can do it in this way:

```
class SendPhoto {

    class func sendPhotoToAssistantAlert() -> CustomAlertView {
        return CustomAlertView(title: "Title")
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I suggest to change your approach in this way if you want to handle the Alamofire upload process:

```
//create a protocol
protocol SendPhoto {
    func sendPhotoToAssistant()
}

//add an extension of your protocol where Self is your UIViewController
extension SendPhoto where Self: UIViewController {
    func sendPhotoToAssistant() {
        //implement here your upload process
        //You now can present here your custom alert view
    }
}
```

Then adopt the SendPhoto protocol for your controller and you can call the function where you need, example:

```
class YourViewController: SendPhoto {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       //this is an example call it where you need
       self.sendPhotoToAssistant()
   }
}
```

Comment: If I want to write completion handler to this func , How I use this ?

Comment: What is your need? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I use Alamofire and I want to write a completion to return Bool for the upload process is completed or not .

Comment: And you want to make the function call inside your UIViewController?

Comment: Absolutely yes.